# I want to validate the following JSON schema in datapower using schema file

Tags: json

```
{
  "email": "005foobar@gmail.com",
  "phone": "9867534210",
  "country_code": "91",
  "firstname":"Rakesh",
  "surname" :"A R"             
}
```

I want either `firstname` or `surname` to be in my request(like one of: "firstname" or "surname")

For example:

```
{
  "email": "005foobar@gmail.com",
  "phone": "9867534210",
  "country_code": "91",
  "firstname":"Rakesh"                                            
}
```

or

```
{
  "email": "005foobar@gmail.com",
  "phone": "9867534210",
  "country_code": "91",
  "surname":"A R"                                
}
```

Can you please help me with the json schema for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

For example something like this. It is a little bit complex, but if you want exactly EITHER surname OR fisrtName but NOT together and NOT absence of them it is what you need.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country_code": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/email"
        },
        "phone": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/phone"
        },
        "county_code": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/country_code"
        },
        "firstname": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "email",
        "phone",
        "country_code",
        "firstname"
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/email"
        },
        "phone": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/phone"
        },
        "county_code": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/country_code"
        },
        "surname": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "email",
        "phone",
        "country_code",
        "surname"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```